# One SQL Server query results into multiple datasets

Tags: sql-server

In a SQL Server stored procedure, the first select statement creates a temp table (#fundnames) containing a list of distinct fundnames. A second select then uses #fundnames to select from portfolio_history to select the histories of each fundname. The output is a single dataset.

```
select  h.valuedate "valuedate", 
        h.fundname "fundname", 
        h.value "value"
FROM    portfolio_history h,
        #fundnames f    
where   f.fundname = h.fundname
order by
        h.fundname asc,
        h.valuedate asc
```

The result set is something like this:

```
valuedate  fundname                                           value
2022-02-04 RLP/BlackrockACSWorld(ExUK)EquityIndex             99999.99
2022-02-05 RLP/BlackrockACSWorld(ExUK)EquityIndex             99999.99
2021-07-20 RLPAbsoluteReturnGovernmentBond                    99999.99
2021-07-23 RLPAbsoluteReturnGovernmentBond                    99999.99
```

What I want is this:

```
valuedate  fundname                                           value
----------------------------------------------------------------------
2022-02-04 RLP/BlackrockACSWorld(ExUK)EquityIndex             99999.99
2022-02-05 RLP/BlackrockACSWorld(ExUK)EquityIndex             99999.99

valuedate  fundname                                           value
----------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-07-20 RLPAbsoluteReturnGovernmentBond                    99999.99
2021-07-23 RLPAbsoluteReturnGovernmentBond                    99999.99
```

Can this be done?

Comment: You want two separate result sets? Write two queries if so.

Comment: FYI, it's **2022**, the ANSI-92 Explicit Join Syntax has been around for **30 years**. Why are you *still* using that 1980's implicit join syntax?

Comment: This would be a rare occasion where a loop with a cursor is an appropriate solution, assuming the number of funds is dynamic, since the only way to produce multiple result sets is to execute multiple statements. It would be very unusual to need this as a requirement of the client, though (most can't process multiple result sets correctly) -- if you're just doing this to get something that prints pretty when viewed as text, you're definitely doing it wrong and should look at more sophisticated client tooling to view the result set (for example, a spreadsheet with a pivot table).

Comment: Agreed, any reasonable client app should be able to split this up without messing about in T-SQL. And why do you need the temp table, why not just join the whole thing together?

Comment: What is the purpose of `#fundnames` in your query ? I don't see any column returns from that at all. All the values returns are from `portfolio_history`

Comment: My best guess, it's a pseudo `EXISTS` clause, @Squirrel .

Comment: Have you considered that your goal will likely require changes to the caller/consumer of the resultsets? TSQL is not a language suited to generating "pretty" formatted information.

Comment: Thanks for the range of comments guys, from the patronising to the useful.

Answer (score 0):

Not multiple datasets. You mean multiple data tables
1 Dataset can have many Data tables

```
-- query 1, produces datatable 1
select * from table1 where date = @date1

-- query 2, produces datatable 2
select * from table1 where date = @date2
```